# Django Admin Interface - Privileges On Development Server

Tags: python, django, database, admin, privileges

I have an old project running (Django 1.6.5, Python 2.7) live for several years. I have to make some changes and have set up a working development environment with all the right django and python requirements (packages, versions, etc.)

Everything is running fine, except when I am trying to make changes inside the admin panel. I can log on fine and looking at the database (sqlite3) I see my user has superuser privileges. However django says "You have no permissions to change anything" and thus not even displaying any of the models registered for the admin interface.

I am using the same database that is running on the live server. There I have no issues at all (Live server also running in development mode with DEBUG=True has no issues) -> I can only see the history (My Change Log) - Nothing else

I have also created a new superuser - but same problem here.

I'd appreciate any pointers (Maybe how to debug this?)

Comment: check for user permissions mostly your user is admin but all page permissions are removed from it. or simply create a new superuser

Comment: as stated in the question, I have already tried that

Comment: Try checking your user in a shell (`manage.py shell`): see if `user.is_superuser`, `user.is_staff` and if `user.has_perm('my_app.add_mymodel')`

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='xxx')
>>> user.is_superuser
**True**
>>> user.is_staff
**True**
>>> user.has_perm('xxx.add_mymodel')
**True**
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue:

`admin.autodiscover()`

was commented out in the project's **urls.py** for some reason. (I may have done that trying to get the project to work in a more recent version of django) - So `admin.site.register` was never called and the `app_dict` never filled. **index.html** template of `django.contrib.admin` then returns

> You don't have permission to edit anything.

or it's equivalent translation (which I find confusing, given that the permissions are correct, only no models were added to the admin dictionary.

I hope this may help anyone running into a similar problem